# SFML Animation on Keypress only moves one frame

Tags: animation, timer, sfml, elapsedtime

I am trying to get my animation to cycle through two images when a directional key is pressed. Currently it switches images on each key press. I have been looking at tutorials and understand that I need some kind of timer to measure each frame time but everything I have tried to implement in to my code so far has  failed so I am just posting my code that works at the moment.

Could anyone explain to me how to go about implementing this please?

```
    void Frog::up(sf::Event event)
{
    sf::IntRect frogUpAnimation[iNumFrames];
    frogUpAnimation[0] = sf::IntRect(13, 362, 21, 23);
    frogUpAnimation[1] = sf::IntRect(46, 367, 21, 23);

    if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Up)
    {
        audio.frogjumpsound();
        frogSprite.move(0.0f, -55.0f);
        iScoreCounter = iScoreCounter + 10;
        iCurrentFrame++;
        if (iCurrentFrame >= iNumFrames) iCurrentFrame = 0;
        frogSprite.setTextureRect(frogUpAnimation[iCurrentFrame]);
    }
}



int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 800), "Frogger");
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);

    sf::Clock timer;
    float fFrameTime = 1.0f / 60.0f;
    float fElapsedTime;

    sf::Event event;

    Game game;
    Frog frog;
    Timer countdown;
    Text text;
    Audio gameaudio;

    gameaudio.music();

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
            }

            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
            {
                game.processKeyPress(event.key.code);

            }

            frog.up(event);
            frog.down(event);
            frog.left(event);
            frog.right(event);

        } // Event loop

        countdown.gametime();

        fElapsedTime = timer.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();
        if (fElapsedTime > fFrameTime)
        {
            timer.restart();
        }

        //Update
        game.checkPads(&frog);
        game.checkWin();
        game.gameOver();
        frog.scorecounter(&countdown);
        frog.update(fElapsedTime);
        game.update(fElapsedTime);
        text.update(fElapsedTime);
        countdown.update(fElapsedTime);
        game.collision(&frog);

        // Drawing
        window.clear();
        window.draw(game);
        window.draw(frog);
        window.draw(countdown);
        window.draw(text);
        window.display();
    } // main loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would only call 'frog.up()', 'frog.left()', etc. when the proper key is pressed. Otherwise, you're calling potentially 4 functions each iteration which do absolutely nothing.

```
if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right) {
    frog.right();
}
else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left) {
    frog.left();
}
```

As for your timer issues, your fElapsedTime and fFrameTime look a little funky. Take a look at https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=10913.0 but I really recommend this guide: https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Source:-AnimatedSprite